# Can you setup a Swing TableColumn to automatically truncate/remove the left/leading characters of a cell when resizing?

Tags: truncation, tablecolumn

I am needing to have the elipses (...) at the beginning/left edge of a cell rather than the end/right edge when the value is too long for the cell width, whether when initially loaded or when resizing the column.

I've tried to handle this by right justifying the column with the code below, hoping it would handle the resizing in the same manner.  However, that is not the case.  It right justifies the values but continues to truncate the right size of the value when too large.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
r.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
appCol.setCellRenderer(r);
```